# how to show dialog box using background services in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I want to implement background service in my flutter app. basically it is a task manager app. where User can create a task and set reminder and this reminder will remind him that he has to do this task.

how can I do this ?? I failed to add background services. I tried using firebase messaging. When i get background message I call that function but the function functions only when app is opened.

please someone help me to do so. recommend some packages and it would be a bigg help if you provide some code snippets.